# Emacs: how to re-mark a previously marked region

Tags: emacs

When using Emacs, I commonly need to perform multiple operations on the same region (often quite large but not a well-defined object such as "entire section", "entire paragraph"). Currently, I have to manually mark the region, execute the first operation, then go back and re-mark the region, and execute the second operation, and repeat...  That's very cumbersome. I wonder if there is any shortcut to re-mark a previously marked region? Or some way to keep a region marked until I tell Emacs to unmark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The script snippets below will bind key-chords `F6`, `C-F6`, `C-S-F6` to manager markers *(vs mark)*. *Markers* move and shrink and grow, as you change text around and between them.  You can use whichever keys you prefer.  Put the code into your `~/.emacs` config file.

- First establish the bounds of the intitial region (mark -- point).
- Then press `F6` to set markers to the bounds of that region.
- Do whatever you need to do...
- Re-establish the bounds of the modified region by pressing `C-F6`.Repeat *"Do.." as need be
- When you have finished use `C-S-F6` to clear the region markers.

---

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f6>") 'set-markers-for-region)
(defun set-markers-for-region ()
  (interactive)
  (make-local-variable 'm1)
  (make-local-variable 'm2)
  (setq m1 (copy-marker (mark)))
  (setq m2 (copy-marker (point))))

(global-set-key (kbd "<C-f6>") 'set-region-from-markers)
(defun set-region-from-markers ()
  (interactive)
  (set-mark m1)
  (goto-char m2))

(global-set-key (kbd "<C-S-f6>") 'unset-region-markers)
(defun unset-region-markers ()
  (interactive)
  (set-marker m1 nil)
  (set-marker m2 nil))
```

Comment: Excellent! This works. I have tried several times and it always worked as expected. Thanks.

Comment: I'm eight years late to the party - see my solution below.

Answer (score 10):

If the region just got unmarked (which Emacs calls "deactivated"), <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd> will remark (a.k.a. "re-activate") it.

Comment: Amazing! Just absurdly useful. Where'd you find this if I may ask? It would be fantastic if there were a compendium of common commands such as this.

Comment: FTR, just be aware that this swaps the beginning and end of the region.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no region history feature in Emacs.  There is the function `pop-mark`, which restores the mark to a previous location taken from the variable `mark-ring`, but it does not set point and thus is useless for restoring old regions.  If you are adept at [Emacs-Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs_Lisp), you could advise function `set-mark` with code that maintains a region ring (similar to the variable `mark-ring`).  Then you could implement a `pop-region` function that behaves similarly to `pop-mark`.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Thanks for letting me know though. I'm not an Elisp expert, so I guess I will have to continue my laborious method.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your repeated operations, you might be able to record a macro using either the "pop-global-mark" command to return to the last mark in the [global mark ring](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Global-Mark-Ring.html) or you can explicitly save your place with the emacs register comand, and then after the 2nd operation, return with the [register command](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Position-Registers.html#Position-Registers). The register command is bit more grunty and a few more key strokes, but I find it reliable.

Answer (score 3):

A common workflow is to `narrow-to-region` (`C-x n n`) and then perform your tasks on the visible region.  Then `widen` (`C-x n w`) to expose the rest of the buffer again when you are done.

Comment: Underrated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use library [**`second-sel.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/second-sel.el) then you can use the [secondary-selection](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SecondarySelection) to help with this. The secondary selection is not associated with point or mark, so it stays put, even as point moves (so yes, unlike the region, it can move off screen).

With this suggested key binding:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-y") 'secondary-yank|select|move|swap)
```

You can do the following:

1. **`C-1 C-M-y`** to select the active region as the secondary selection.
2. Do whatever else you need to do: move around, select other text (change the region), whatever.
3. When you want to put the region back where it was, which is where the secondary selection still is, just use **`C-0 C-M-y`**.

That's all. Just `C-1 C-M-y` to take a snapshot of the region (as the secondary), and later `C-0 C-M-y` to activate the region where it was at the time of the snapshot.

---

You can also use **`C-- C-M-y`** to swap the region and the secondary selection.  So for example, if `cat` is the (active) region and `dog` is the secondary then `C-- C-M-y` makes `cat` the secondary and `dog` the (active) region.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution has the advantages of requiring only a single function and single keybinding:

```
(defun my-reuse-region (unset)
  "Enable re-use of regions.

When a region is selected, save its bounds for future use.
Otherwise, activate the saved bounds. With a prefix argument,
unsets any prior saved bounds."
  (interactive "P")
  (cond
   (unset
    (makunbound 'my-reusable-mark)
    (makunbound 'my-reusable-mark))
   ((region-active-p)
     (when (not (boundp 'my-reusable-mark))
       (make-local-variable 'my-reusable-mark))
     (when (not (boundp 'my-reusable-point))
       (make-local-variable 'my-reusable-point))
     (setq my-reusable-mark (copy-marker (mark)))
     (setq my-reusable-point (copy-marker (point)))
     (message "Region bounds saved for future use."))
   (t
     (when (and (boundp 'my-reusable-mark)
                (boundp 'my-reusable-point))
       (set-mark my-reusable-mark)
       (goto-char my-reusable-point)))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-SPC") 'my-reuse-region)
```

Note: I'm not really certain there is a use-case for calling the function with a prefix argument; I added that code just to be conscientious and thorough.